# Proper mode for ntp parse clock driver

Tags: ntp, dcf77

I am currently setting up a NTP stratum 1 time server with a DIY DCF77 clock. According to the [documentation](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/drivers/driver8.html) I need to configure one of the lines below.

```
# Walter Schmid DCF receiver Kit (AM demodulation / 1ms)
#server 127.127.8.0 mode 4

# RAW DCF77 100/200ms pulses (Conrad DCF77 receiver module / 5ms)
#server 127.127.8.0 mode 5

# RAW DCF77 100/200ms pulses (TimeBrick DCF77 receiver module / 5ms)
#server 127.127.8.0 mode 6

# RAWDCF receiver (DTR=high/RTS=low)
#server 127.127.8.0 mode 14

# RAWDCF receiver (DTR=low/RTS=high) 
#server 127.127.8.0 mode 16
```

Unfortunately the documentation does not provide much detail about the differences between those drivers. Has anyone a hint which one I should chose and why?

Comment: I have to imagine the expectation is that if you built your own DCF77 clock you would know what signals it was sending. How does the clock you built communicate? It also looks like you did a quick grep and missed modes 20 and 21.

Comment: I communicates any protocoll I want. The question is what do the different drivers expect? I can generate a "raw" stream like e.g. the Conrad module. However I wonder why there are so many different drivers. With regard to mode 20 and 21 this is an interesting hint. So there are differences in the baud rate. OK. But still what are the other modes good for? The prolific stuff should not be relevant to me as I use FTDI chipsets as a serial bridge.

Comment: Use the source luke! Grab the latest ntpd tarball and look in the libparse and parseutil directories as well as ntpd/refclock_parse.c

Comment: OK, I used the source --> it seems I would be better of with the Meinberg Protocoll (127.127.8.0 mode 2). I changed my DIY clock accordingly. Still no success but this is a different issue. I think I have to dig a little deeper into the configuration.

Comment: Found out that I linked with relock-0 instead of refclock-0. Now it works perfectly well as a "Meinberg DCF clock" :)